# Why are there no line breaks in my labels even though I added \n?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm having an issue with creating multi-line labels in QGIS.  I believe I have the syntax right in the label expression because the output preview looks correct.  However, on the map, everything displays on the same line.  If anyone can help, let me know - I'm new to both QGIS and StackExchange.  Screenshots are below.

[image: Label expression and output preview]

[image: Map rendering]

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Which version of QGIS do you use? Is your point layer a .shp or a table from database? Is the background map provided by OpenLayers plugin?

Comment: Try `\r\n` (sometimes Windows needs both characters because, well, Windows)

Answer (score 2):

Strange, works for me just fine.

Here is my attributes table:

[image]

And I applied this to *layer Properties* > *Labels* > *Formatting*

[image]

And I get this:

[image]

Are you clicking the button next to **"Label this layer with"** to include your filter?

Comment: I don't think this answer is helpful. Topic starter obviously made all these steps.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "wrap on character" field in formatting has to be empty for \n to work.

Comment: Awesome, this was the key.  I thought I had to have the \n in the wrap on character field, didn't realize this was the default.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @underdark, perhaps you should post your comment as an answer since you were right on the money :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Windows. You should try `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

I'm currently not in a position to check if this would work, so if that doesn't work, please leave a comment below and I will delete this answer.